# Numpy genfromtxt Column Names

Tags: python, numpy

How can I have `genfromtxt` to return me its `list` of column names which were automatically retrieved by `names=True`? When I do:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("test.csv",names=True,delimiter=",",dtype=None)
print data['col1']
```

it prints the entire column values for `col1`.

**However, I need to traverse all column names. How can I do that?**

I tried `data.keys()` and various other methods, but whatever is returned by `genfromtxt` does not seem to be a dictionary compatible object. I guess I could pass the `list` of column names myself, but this won't be maintainable for me in the long run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`genfromtxt`returns a [numpy.ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

You can get the data type with

```
data.dtype
```

or just the names with

```
data.dtype.names
```

which is a tuple you can iterate over and access the columns as you want to.